# Are Checkboxes or Chips the best UX for large number of choices?

Tags: choices

I have a design requirement to list all the industry sectors and the user must choose one or more industry sectors which apply. Here is a list of all the industry sectors:

```
A. Agriculture, forestry and fishing
B. Mining and quarrying
C. Manufacturing
D. Electricity, gas, steam and air conditioning supply
E. Water supply; sewerage, waste management and remediation activities
F. Construction
G. Wholesale and retail trade; repair of motor vehicles and motorcycles
H. Transportation and storage
I. Accommodation and food service activities
J. Information and communication
K. Financial and insurance activities
L. Real estate activities
M. Professional, scientific and technical activities
N. Administrative and support service activities
O. Public administration and defence; compulsory social security
P. Education
Q. Human health and social work activities
R. Arts, entertainment and recreation
S. Other service activities
T. Activities of households as employers; undifferentiated goods- and services-producing activities of households for own use
U. Activities of extraterritorial organizations and bodies
```

Would these better be represented as material ui chips or checkboxes?

[image: chips]

[image: checkbox]

Comment: I don't know if you should do chips or checkboxes but if you go chips I'd think the ["Filter Chips"](https://material.io/components/chips/#filter-chips) would be a better options since they're meant for multiple selections where "Choice Chips" like you show says it's for a single selection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would go with the checkboxes. The issue you'll run into, from what I can see in your list, is going with the Choice Chip option will create really long Chips. That is if you're going to be placing the copy verbatim. Also, it states under the usage guidelines that the chips are meant for "...single selection from a set of options." The chips work best for short, single words. Checkboxes will provide a vertical line of sight down the page. If you need to, break them up by section so that it's easier to read and locate specific options.